# How to identify each visitors country/location using php?

Tags: php, locale, country

Hai friends I need user country when they visit my php website. According to his country I have to do some checking when they upload some bulk informations.

How can I find the visitor country using php.

Comment: you can get the ip and found out the country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has no built-in method to determine the location of a website visitor.

The best you can do automatically is to look up their IP address in an IP-to-location database.

You can get one for [free from MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity). They have a [PHP API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) available for using the database.

Comment: +1 , GeoIP is hard to beat for the price, esp the free version.

Comment: Well, this are good but they update their db occasionally. So if anybody use this, make sure your db is up to date otherwise you will not be able to get a good result.